# GRUB: Error 28: Selected item cannot fit into memory

Tags: grub

Yesterday, I had an issue with my laptop: it didn't boot any longer. On startup, grub was started, but not with the normal menu, but just with a command line.

When I tried to enter commands (which weren't echoed), it gave me the error mentionned in the title.

I then booted the PC with a resue USB stick tried to re-install grub, but that didn't help either.

I give the solution in an answer below, but would like to know what was the real reason...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there were — among others — two files in my `/boot/grub/`: `stage2` and `stage2.old`. The latter hat a file date of January 2012, while the former has been changed in the last days. I replaced `stage2` with `stage2.old` and it worked again.

Nevertheless, I would like to know if anybody else had this issue as well and maybe knows where this file change came from...

Comment: I am also having the same problem, but the solution you posted is not working in my case.